# Failing freeing a 2d dimensional array dynamically allocated

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char** baz_alloc(int size)
{
    char ** b = malloc((size+1) * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        b[i] = "baz";
    b[size] = NULL;

    return b;
}

void baz_print(char** baz)
{
    char** b = baz;
    while (*b != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", *b);
        b++;
    }
}

void baz_free(char** baz)
{       
    int len = 0;
    char** b = baz;
    for (; *b != NULL; len++, b++);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        free(baz[i]);
    free(baz);
}

int main()
{
    char** baz = baz_alloc(10);
    baz_print(baz);
    baz_free(baz);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The program crashes at the call to the `free` function. I've looked at similar example here at SO and it looks pretty much the same. What is wrong in my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `free()` on this pointer:

```
b[i] = "baz"
```

That pointer wasn't allocated with `malloc()` (or `calloc()`, `realloc()`, etc).

Answer (score 3):

You can't free a string litteral

```
free(baz[i]);
```

tries to free from

```
b[i] = "baz";
```

As a rule: Only free what you allocated, where you allocated it (in the topmost function causing the allocation), in reverse allocating order.

For example :

```
int main()
{
  char** baz = baz_alloc(10); //'creating' baz
  baz_print(baz); //using baz
  baz_free(baz); //freeing baz
  [...]
}
```

Is very good practice.

Your `baz_free` function only needs to use 1 `free` as only 1 `malloc` was called in `baz_alloc`:

```
//Allocation
char ** b = malloc((size+1) * sizeof(char*));

//Freeing
free(b); // or in your function free(baz);
```

If your `baz_alloc` function had `b[i] = malloc(...)` your `baz_free` code would be -almost- correct (You don't need to iterate twice, you could call `free(b)` in your first loop).

Answer (score 1):

this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    free(baz[i]);
```

should not exist because the memory was never allocated.

However the following line:

```
free(baz);
```

needs to be there as the initial array of pointers to char was created via a call to malloc().